# Textview text in multiline, Listview in Scrollview

Tags: android

I am using a `listview` in `scrollview`. I am able to show the list in `listview` in Scrollview using below method.

```
public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView myListView) {
    ListAdapter myListAdapter = myListView.getAdapter();
    if (myListAdapter == null) {
        // do nothing return null
        return;
    }
    // set listAdapter in loop for getting final size
    int totalHeight = 0;
    for (int size = 0; size < myListAdapter.getCount(); size++) {
        View listItem = myListAdapter.getView(size, null, myListView);
        listItem.measure(0, 0);
        totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
    }
    // setting listview item in adapter
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = myListView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight
            + (myListView.getDividerHeight() * (myListAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    myListView.setLayoutParams(params);
    // print height of adapter on log
    Log.i("height of listItem:", String.valueOf(totalHeight));
}
```

There is a `textview` in `listview` and the `textview`'s text is too long and it comes in 3 or 4 lines. In that case, the `listview` is not showing all items.

Comment: `I am using listview in scrollview` this is a **bad design**

Comment: why not you set textView xml property android:layout_height="wrap_content" ?

Comment: I already did layout:height ="wrap_content" but instead of that listview not showing all items,for example arraylist size is 10. then it is showing only 6 items ,The reason is that In every item of listview textview's text is so long and it's coming in 2 or 3 lines, and I am using above method for showing listview in scrollview.please help me.